# Is it possible to restrict the touch pass to the current touched view(say the view loaded inside any view)?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using ListView control in Xamarin.Forms. In that, I have loaded a Label view as child view using ItemTemplate in ListView like below,

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="MyLabel"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Now, if I touch the label, events related to the label only triggered since the touch is passed to Label view. But I need to trigger the touch events of the parent view(here ListView) i.e., need to pass the touch to ListView.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to achieve this in Xamarin.Forms.

Set the "InputTransparent" property of Label view to "false" as below,

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="MyLabel" InputTransparent="true"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

So, the touch will be passed to the parent view. i.e, ListView in your case.